# When I create a table in iOS7, the label in the cell appears to be much smaller than the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uilabel

I have an iPhone app which i'm currently testing with iOS7. I've noticed a few changes such as iOS7 not taking into account nav bars and tab bars when giving the screen size and I've accounted for that. However, one thing I haven't been able to account for is that when I create a table view, the text label appears to be. I've tried running it in iOS6.1 and it runs fine there.

To set the text, I do this:

```
label_p.text = sText_p;
label_p.font = [UIFont fontWithName: [font_p returnFontName] size: [font_p getFontSizeValue]];
label_p.numberOfLines = 0;
label_p.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

I'm using the smallest font I can but it's still not helping the issue. When I run the app with the numberOfLines variable set to 1, it shows the text correctly but then the UILineBreakModeWordWrap setting for lineBreakMode stops working and text runs off the end of the label without wrapping. Is this a problem that anyone else has come across when migrating to iOS7?

Comment: do you have a custom cell with a label inside? is the autolayout enabled?

Comment: How have you created your label ?

Comment: You should use NSLineBreakModeWordWrap, might help.

Comment: Hi, Yes it's a custom cell with a label inside. Autolayout isn't enabled though. The label is already created. I tried changing the label's size in the xib file but that didn't help. I then did frame.size.height = 30 and that had the same effect as setting the numberOfLines variable to 1. A point to add would be that when I do that, part of the cell's border turns white for some reason, in case that's any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to NSLineBreakModeWordWrap hasn't helped. What I don't get is what has changed between iOS6 and 7 which has caused this to happen...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. For some reason in iOS 7, you need to call [label sizeToFit] but not in previous versions of iOS.